# Issue in sending verification code from registeration form in DNN

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I am using a custom dnn registration form with User Registration:Verified.

Below is the code:

```
TokenReplace tr = new TokenReplace(Scope.SystemMessages, User.Profile.PreferredLocale, this.PortalSettings, this.User);
string verificationCode = tr.ReplaceEnvironmentTokens("[User:VerificationCode]");
string verificationUrl = Globals.NavigateURL(PortalSettings.LoginTabId) + "?username=" + Server.UrlEncode(User.Username) + "&verificationcode=" + Server.UrlEncode(verificationCode);
```

In this code i get the value of `verificationCode=*******`

Please help me over here why verificationCode is not shown in clear text format.

Many-2 thanks to you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The token is being replaced with asterisks because the AccessingUser (the user that is running the above code), does not have sufficient permission to meet the access scope level required to display the verification code.

In the UserInfo class GetProperty method, it requires the "AccessingUser" to either be an administrator, or the user himself in order for the token to be rendered without being masked.  It determines the accessing user via HttpContext.Current.Items("UserInfo"), so to allow the token to render properly, you will need to set the accessing user to the portal administrator before calling the ReplaceEnvironmentTokens function.

Example:

```
TokenReplace tr = new TokenReplace(Scope.SystemMessages, User.Profile.PreferredLocale, this.PortalSettings, this.User); 

tr.AccessingUser = New UserController().GetUser(objPortal.PortalId, PortalSettings.AdministratorId)

string verificationCode = tr.ReplaceEnvironmentTokens("[User:VerificationCode]");
string verificationUrl = Globals.NavigateURL(PortalSettings.LoginTabId) + "?username=" + Server.UrlEncode(User.Username) + "&verificationcode=" + Server.UrlEncode(verificationCode);
```

Comment: Hmm - even when I pass in an Admin user the result is still ******* - see http://www.dnnsoftware.com/answers/ReplaceEnvironmentTokens-UserVerificationCode-stopped-working-in-73